# Java : add node in sorted doubly linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to add few nodes in a sorted doubly linked list. There is something wrong with the code which I am not able to figure out . I created two nodes current and prev which will help in traversing.

```
/*
  Insert Node at the end of a linked list 
  head pointer input could be NULL as well for empty list
  Node is defined as 
  class Node {
     int data;
     Node next;
     Node prev;
  }
*/

Node sortedInsert(Node head, int data) {
    Node newnode = new Node();
    newnode.data = data;
    Node current = head;
    Node pre = null;
    if(head == null) {
        head = newnode;
        newnode.prev = null;
    } 
    else if (head.data >= newnode.data) {
        newnode.next = head;
        head.prev = newnode;
        head = newnode;
        return newnode;
    }

    while(current!=null && current.data <= newnode.data) {
        pre = current;
        current = current.next;

        newnode.prev = pre;
        pre.next = newnode;
        newnode.next = current;
        if (current != null) {
            current.prev = newnode;
        }
    }
    return head;      
}
```

Comment: "There is something wrong with the code which I am not able to figure out" - what's wrong?

Comment: even I am not able to figure out. it is working only when head is null

Comment: what is the input data you're using to reproduce the error?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is something wrong"? How do you know something is wrong - are you getting an error? What behavior are you seeing and what behavior are you expecting? That's what Leo is asking.

Comment: Yeah @Ciara i just tested on hackerRank and it is nit working. It is not passing any of the test cases.

Comment: 1. the " if(head == null) " misses a return statement. 2, the "else if" is then an "if" 3. your code modifies all nodes, instead of performing one insert at the correct location. So all visited nodes are corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following problems:

- The `if (head == null)` misses a return-statement.
- The `else if` is then an `if`.
- Your code modifies all nodes, instead of performing one insert at the correct location, so all visited nodes are corrupted.

Here is a working version:

```
Node sortedInsert(Node head, int data) {
    Node newnode = new Node();
    newnode.data = data;

    // head is null -> new Node is new list
    if (head == null)
        return newnode;

    // handle special case if data < head.data
    if (data < head.data) {
        newnode.next = head;
        head.prev = newnode;
        return newnode; // newnode is the new list head
    }

    // search position in list
    Node prev = head;
    for (; prev.next != null; prev = prev.next) {
        if (prev.next.data > data)
            break;
    }

    // insert behind prev
    newnode.next = prev.next;
    if (prev.next != null) {
        prev.next.prev = newnode;
    }
    prev.next = newnode;
    newnode.prev = prev;

    return head; // head did not change
}
```

Comment: You code is great but I want to know, what's wrong with my code